# Efficient method to smooth data in R

Tags: r

This question is related to another question which I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236949/how-to-sum-a-function-over-a-specific-range-in-r).

## Data

My data frame contains velocities and accelerations of vehicles in every 0.1 seconds time frames. Following shows very few data points of the data frame which originally contains more than 1,000,000 rows:

```
> dput(head(traj2[, c(1,2,12,13)], 30))
structure(list(Vehicle.ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Frame.ID = 270:299, Vehicle.velocity = c(19.89, 
19.89, 19.89, 19.89, 19.89, 19.97, 20, 19.86, 19.18, 18.17, 17.63, 
17.87, 18.76, 19.67, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 19.99, 19.98), Vehicle.acceleration = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 1.07, 0.6, 0, -2.42, -9.79, -11.2, -2.64, 9.2, 11.2, 5.32, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.11, -0.2)), .Names = c("Vehicle.ID", 
"Frame.ID", "Vehicle.velocity", "Vehicle.acceleration"), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Please note that there are about 2000 unique `Vehicle.ID`s, each repeating in different number of frames.

## Goal

I want to smooth the velocities and accelerations by using the equation provided in the first question. But I want to minimize the time and make the code as efficient as possible.

## What I have Tried

I used following code for smoothing:

```
#  VELOCITY SMOOTHING FUNCTION
smooth <- function (x, D, delta){
z <- exp(-abs(-D:D/delta))
r <- convolve (x, z, type='filter')/convolve(rep(1, length(x)),z,type='filter')
r
}
#  ACCELERATION SMOOTHING FUNCTION
smootha <- function (x, D, delta){
  za <- exp(-abs(-D:D/delta))
  ra <- convolve (x, za, type='filter')/convolve(rep(1, length(x)),za,type='filter')
  ra
} ### D=3*delta = 3*40 = 120, delta for acceleration = T / dt = 4 seconds/0.1 = 40
ftaa <- list()


 # Split data by vehicle ID
    length(ftaa) <- length(unique(traj1$'Vehicle.ID'))

# Apply smoothing function
for (i in 1:length(unique(traj2$'Vehicle.ID'))){
  veh <- subset (traj2, traj2$'Vehicle.ID'==unique(traj2$'Vehicle.ID')[i])
  svel <- round(smooth(veh$'Vehicle.velocity',30,10), digits=2)
  svel <- data.frame(svel)
  svel <- head(tail(svel,-90),-90)
  sacc <- round(smootha(veh$'Vehicle.acceleration',120,40), digits=2)
  sacc <- data.frame(sacc)
  veh <- head(tail(veh, -120), -120)
  ftaa[[i]] <- cbind(veh,svel,sacc)
}

# Combining results
final.data1<-do.call("rbind", ftaa)
```

## The Problem

This approach takes about 40 minutes to complete smoothing the given data frame. Is there any way I could reduce this time?

Comment: Did you try summaryRprof("profile1.out",lines="show") [..]Rprof(NULL) [..] summaryRprof("profile1.out",lines="show") to find out the "bad lines"? Profiling might help to find the expensive computations.

Comment: Also, be careful with your function names, 'smooth()' is an already existing base function.

Comment: @Marc I have no idea about the summaryRprof thing you mentioned. What is profiling? +nfmcclure I've changed the name of smooth function but it's still taking long.

Comment: Can you please explain with more detail what you want to do?  smooth and smootha don't seem to return vectors.  Is that what you want?  What is the head(tail stuff attempting to do?

Comment: @umairdurrani Profiling is to find bottlenecks. You can execute a function, and R tells you, how long each call takes. That makes it pretty easy to find out which lines/which commands are inperformant or need work. Here's a little tutorial. [link](http://www.r-bloggers.com/profiling-r-code/) It's not hard and worth a while. BTW: your smooth and smoothA function do the same thing. You can throw one of them out. (Or am I missing something?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend ditching the loop and using `data.table`.  Also, why not use the `round` function inside of your `smooth` and `smootha` functions?

```
require(data.table)
setDT(traj2)

traj2[ , svel := smooth(Vehicle.velocity,30,10), by =Vehicle.ID]
traj2[ , sacc := smootha(Vehicle.acceleration,120,40), by =Vehicle.ID]
```

This is difficult to test because your problem is not setup in a reproducible way.  Your smoothing functions need identically sized vectors (your link shows using convolve with `type="open"` instead of how you are using it).  But this is a good template for getting your code to run much much faster.

Comment: This works amazingly fast! Thank you so much. The `setDT` command did not work (`data.table` version 1.8.10), so I used `data.table(traj2)` instead. Any tips where I could learn `data.table` package commands (the vignette is not easy to understand)?

Comment: also...if you are a SQL user, you can think of it as ```data[ where , select, by][order]```.  Also, could you tell us how fast it runs now using ```data.table```?

Comment: Thank you very much. It takes 2 seconds to complete the smoothing process. I have one question: When velocity was smoothed, it used 30 as `D` in the `smoothv` function. The final result `svel` contains 60 values (30 + 30) in the `tail` which are redundant. They are same as the first 60 values. Shouldn't the smoothed data be attached to the original one between 1st and last 30 values?

Comment: I think the last 60 redundant values in `svel` should be removed. Also, the 1st and last 30 values of the data frame should be removed. Finally the new variable `svel` should be combined with the data frame. Is there any direct way to achieve this using `data.table`?