# Data Smoothing in R

Tags: r, dplyr

This question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236949/how-to-sum-a-function-over-a-specific-range-in-r) that I asked before. But referring to that question is not necessary to answer this one.

## Data

I have a data set containing velocities of 2169 vehicles recorded at intervals of 0.1 seconds. So, there are many rows for an individual vehicle. Here I am reproducing the data only for the vehicle # 2:

```
> dput(uma)
structure(list(Frame.ID = 13:445, Vehicle.velocity = c(40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40.02, 40.03, 39.93, 39.61, 39.14, 38.61, 
38.28, 38.42, 38.78, 38.92, 38.54, 37.51, 36.34, 35.5, 35.08, 
34.96, 34.98, 35, 34.99, 34.98, 35.1, 35.49, 36.2, 37.15, 38.12, 
38.76, 38.95, 38.95, 38.99, 39.18, 39.34, 39.2, 38.89, 38.73, 
38.88, 39.28, 39.68, 39.94, 40.02, 40, 39.99, 39.99, 39.65, 38.92, 
38.52, 38.8, 39.72, 40.76, 41.07, 40.8, 40.59, 40.75, 41.38, 
42.37, 43.37, 44.06, 44.29, 44.13, 43.9, 43.92, 44.21, 44.59, 
44.87, 44.99, 45.01, 45.01, 45, 45, 45, 44.79, 44.32, 43.98, 
43.97, 44.29, 44.76, 45.06, 45.36, 45.92, 46.6, 47.05, 47.05, 
46.6, 45.92, 45.36, 45.06, 44.96, 44.97, 44.99, 44.99, 44.99, 
44.99, 45.01, 45.02, 44.9, 44.46, 43.62, 42.47, 41.41, 40.72, 
40.49, 40.6, 40.76, 40.72, 40.5, 40.38, 40.43, 40.38, 39.83, 
38.59, 37.02, 35.73, 35.04, 34.85, 34.91, 34.99, 34.99, 34.97, 
34.96, 34.98, 35.07, 35.29, 35.54, 35.67, 35.63, 35.53, 35.53, 
35.63, 35.68, 35.55, 35.28, 35.06, 35.09, 35.49, 36.22, 37.08, 
37.8, 38.3, 38.73, 39.18, 39.62, 39.83, 39.73, 39.58, 39.57, 
39.71, 39.91, 40, 39.98, 39.97, 40.08, 40.38, 40.81, 41.27, 41.69, 
42.2, 42.92, 43.77, 44.49, 44.9, 45.03, 45.01, 45, 45, 45, 45, 
45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 44.99, 45.03, 45.26, 45.83, 46.83, 
48.2, 49.68, 50.95, 51.83, 52.19, 52, 51.35, 50.38, 49.38, 48.63, 
48.15, 47.87, 47.78, 48.01, 48.63, 49.52, 50.39, 50.9, 50.96, 
50.68, 50.3, 50.05, 49.94, 49.87, 49.82, 49.82, 49.88, 49.96, 
50, 50, 49.98, 49.98, 50.16, 50.64, 51.43, 52.33, 53.01, 53.27, 
53.22, 53.25, 53.75, 54.86, 56.36, 57.64, 58.28, 58.29, 57.94, 
57.51, 57.07, 56.64, 56.43, 56.73, 57.5, 58.27, 58.55, 58.32, 
57.99, 57.89, 57.92, 57.74, 57.12, 56.24, 55.51, 55.1, 54.97, 
54.98, 55.02, 55.03, 54.86, 54.3, 53.25, 51.8, 50.36, 49.41, 
49.06, 49.17, 49.4, 49.51, 49.52, 49.51, 49.45, 49.24, 48.84, 
48.29, 47.74, 47.33, 47.12, 47.06, 47.07, 47.08, 47.05, 47.04, 
47.25, 47.68, 47.93, 47.56, 46.31, 44.43, 42.7, 41.56, 41.03, 
40.92, 40.92, 40.98, 41.19, 41.45, 41.54, 41.32, 40.85, 40.37, 
40.09, 39.99, 39.99, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
39.98, 39.97, 40.1, 40.53, 41.36, 42.52, 43.71, 44.57, 45.01, 
45.1, 45.04, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 44.98, 44.97, 45.08, 45.39, 
45.85, 46.2, 46.28, 46.21, 46.29, 46.74, 47.49, 48.35, 49.11, 
49.63, 49.89, 49.94, 49.97, 50.14, 50.44, 50.78, 51.03, 51.12, 
51.05, 50.85, 50.56, 50.26, 50.06, 50.1, 50.52, 51.36, 52.5, 
53.63, 54.46, 54.9, 55.03, 55.09, 55.23, 55.35, 55.35, 55.23, 
55.07, 54.99, 54.98, 54.97, 55.06, 55.37, 55.91, 56.66, 57.42, 
58.07, 58.7, 59.24, 59.67, 59.95, 60.02, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 
60.01, 60.06, 60.23, 60.65, 61.34, 62.17, 62.93, 63.53, 64, 64.41, 
64.75, 65.04, 65.3, 65.57, 65.75, 65.74, 65.66, 65.62, 65.71, 
65.91, 66.1, 66.26, 66.44, 66.61, 66.78, 66.91, 66.99, 66.91, 
66.7, 66.56, 66.6, 66.83, 67.17, 67.45, 67.75, 68.15, 68.64, 
69.15, 69.57, 69.79, 69.79, 69.72, 69.72, 69.81, 69.94, 70, 70.01, 
70.02, 70.03)), .Names = c("Frame.ID", "Vehicle.velocity"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
433L))
```

Frame.ID is the time frame in which the Vehicle.velocity was observed. There is some noise in the velocity variable and I want to smooth it.

## Methodology

To smooth the velocity I am using following equation:

[image: equation]

where,
Delta = 10
Nalpha = number of data points (rows)
i = 1, ... ,Nalpha (i.e. the row number)
D = minimum of {i-1, Nalpha - i, 3*delta=30}
xalpha = velocity

## Question

I have gone through the documentation of `filter` and `convolution` in R. It seems that I have to know about convolution to do this. However, I have tried my best and can't understand how convolution works! The linked question has an answer which helped me in understanding some of the inner workings in the function but I am still not sure.
Could anyone here on SO please explain how this thing works? Or guide me to an alternative methodology to achieve the same purpose i.e. apply the equation?

## My current code which works but is lengthy

Here is what `uma` looks like:

```
> head(uma)
  Frame.ID Vehicle.velocity
1       13               40
2       14               40
3       15               40
4       16               40
5       17               40
6       18               40

uma$i <- 1:nrow(uma)             # this is i
uma$im1 <- uma$i - 1
uma$Nai <- nrow(uma) - uma$i     # this is Nalpha 
uma$delta3 <- 30                 # this is 3 times delta
uma$D <- pmin(uma$im1, uma$Nai, uma$delta3)  # selecting the minimum of {i-1, Nalpha - i, 3*delta=15}
uma$imD <- uma$i - uma$D         # i-D
uma$ipD <- uma$i + uma$D         # i+D

uma <- ddply(uma, .(Frame.ID), transform, k = imD:ipD)  # to include all k in the data frame
umai <- uma
umai$imk <- umai$i - umai$k      # i-k
umai$aimk <- (-1) * abs(umai$imk)  # -|i-k|
umai$delta <- 10                  
umai$kernel <- exp(umai$aimk/umai$delta)   # The kernel in the equation i.e. EXP^-|i-k|/delta
umai$p <- umai$Vehicle.velocity[match(umai$k,umai$i)]   #observed velocity in kth row as described in equation as t(k)
umai$kernelp <- umai$p * umai$kernel       # the product of kernel and observed velocity in kth row as described in equation as t(k)
umair <- ddply(umai, .(Frame.ID), summarize, Z = sum(kernel), prod = sum(kernelp))  # summing the kernel to get Z and summing the product to get the numerator of the equation
umair$new.Y <- umair$prod/umair$Z   # the final step to get the smoothed velocity
```

## Plot

Just for reference, if I plot the observed and smoothed velocities against time frames we can see the result of smoothing:

```
ggplot() + 
       geom_point(data=uma,aes(y=Vehicle.velocity, x= Frame.ID)) + 
  geom_point(data=umair,aes(y=new.Y, x= Frame.ID), color="red")
```

[image: smooth]

Please help me making my code short and applicable to all vehicles (represented by Vehicle.ID in the data set)  by guiding me about use of convolution.

## dplyr

Alright, so I used following code and it works but takes 3 hours on 32 GB RAM. Can anyone suggest improvements to speed it up (1 hour each is taken by `umal`, `umav` and `umaa`)?

```
uma <- tbl_df(uma)
uma <- uma %>%     # take data frame 
  group_by(Vehicle.ID)  %>%  # group by Vehicle ID
  mutate(i = 1:length(Frame.ID), im1 = i-1, Nai = length(Frame.ID) - i,
         Dv = pmin(im1, Nai, 30),
         Da = pmin(im1, Nai, 120),
         Dl = pmin(im1, Nai, 15),

         imDv = i - Dv,
         ipDv = i + Dv,
         imDa = i - Da,
         ipDa = i + Da,
         imDl = i - Dl,
         ipDl = i + Dl) %>%  # finding i, i-1 and Nalpha-i, D, i-D and i+D for location, velocity and acceleration
  ungroup()



umav <- uma %>%
  group_by(Vehicle.ID, Frame.ID) %>%
  do(data.frame(kv = .$imDv:.$ipDv)) %>%
  left_join(x=., y=uma) %>%
  mutate(imk = i - kv, aimk = (-1) * abs(imk), delta = 10, kernel = exp(aimk/delta)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Vehicle.ID) %>%
  mutate(p = Vehicle.velocity2[match(kv,i)], kernelp = p * kernel) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Vehicle.ID, Frame.ID) %>%
  summarise(Z = sum(kernel), prod = sum(kernelp)) %>%
  mutate(svel = prod/Z) %>%
  ungroup()



umaa <- uma %>%
  group_by(Vehicle.ID, Frame.ID) %>%
  do(data.frame(ka = .$imDa:.$ipDa)) %>%
  left_join(x=., y=uma) %>%
  mutate(imk = i - ka, aimk = (-1) * abs(imk), delta = 10, kernel = exp(aimk/delta)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Vehicle.ID) %>%
  mutate(p = Vehicle.acceleration2[match(ka,i)], kernelp = p * kernel) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Vehicle.ID, Frame.ID) %>%
  summarise(Z = sum(kernel), prod = sum(kernelp)) %>%
  mutate(sacc = prod/Z) %>%
  ungroup()




umal <- uma %>%
  group_by(Vehicle.ID, Frame.ID) %>%
  do(data.frame(kl = .$imDl:.$ipDl)) %>%
  left_join(x=., y=uma) %>%
  mutate(imk = i - kl, aimk = (-1) * abs(imk), delta = 10, kernel = exp(aimk/delta)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Vehicle.ID) %>%
  mutate(p = Local.Y[match(kl,i)], kernelp = p * kernel) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Vehicle.ID, Frame.ID) %>%
  summarise(Z = sum(kernel), prod = sum(kernelp)) %>%
  mutate(ycoord = prod/Z) %>%
  ungroup()

umal <- select(umal,c("Vehicle.ID", "Frame.ID", "ycoord"))
umav <- select(umav, c("Vehicle.ID", "Frame.ID", "svel"))
umaa <- select(umaa, c("Vehicle.ID", "Frame.ID", "sacc"))

umair <- left_join(uma, umal) %>% left_join(x=., y=umav) %>% left_join(x=., y=umaa)
```

Comment: I modified the code for all vehicles. `ddply` with `transform` has taken 1 hour so far and still running! I really need your help.

Comment: When `ddply` takes too long the usual response is to switch to a more efficient strategy such as packages: data.table or dplyr

Comment: Not sure what your goal with this project is, but from a climate perspective I hope you can help bring transportation into the fold. So it seem to me that you've furnished some type of discrete Fourier transformation. At any rate I think your missing larger points. I'm susceptible to that, but you don't need this method to communicate what you want. I'm not saying R in general of course... I just think your going down a wrong path.

Comment: @miles2know I didn't understand when you said "I just think your going down a wrong path". Are you concerned about the methodology?

Comment: @BondedDust Thanks for the suggestion. I am trying dplyr.

Comment: Sorry... I was confused by the way you presented your question. Are you looking for better ways to process data, to present it or maybe even analyse it? I'ts hard to get a quick read on what your goal is. aside from that...cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good first step would be to take a for loop (which I'll hide with `sapply`) and perform the exponential smoothing for each index:

```
josilber1 <- function(uma) {
  delta <- 10
  sapply(1:nrow(uma), function(i) {
    D <- min(i-1, nrow(uma)-i, 30)
    rng <- (i-D):(i+D)
    rng <- rng[rng >= 1 & rng <= nrow(uma)]
    expabs <- exp(-abs(i-rng)/delta)
    return(sum(uma$Vehicle.velocity[rng] * expabs) / sum(expabs))
  })
}
```

A more involved approach would be to only compute the incremental change in the exponential smoothing function for each index (as opposed to re-summing at each index). The exponential smoothing function has a lower part (data before the current index; I include the current index in `low` in the code below) and an upper part (data after the current index; `high` in the code below). As we loop through the vector, all the data in the lower part gets weighted less (we divide by `mult`) and all the data in the upper part gets weighted more (we multiply by `mult`). The leftmost element is dropped from `low`, the leftmost element in `high` moves to `low`, and one element is added to the right side of `high`.

The actual code is a bit messier to deal with the beginning and ending of the vector and to deal with numerical stability issues (errors in `high` are multiplied by `mult` each iteration):

```
josilber2 <- function(uma) {
  delta <- 10
  x <- uma$Vehicle.velocity
  ret <- c(x[1], rep(NA, nrow(uma)-1))
  low <- x[1]
  high <- 0
  norm <- 1
  old.D <- 0
  mult <- exp(1/delta)
  for (i in 2:nrow(uma)) {
    D <- min(i-1, nrow(uma)-i, 30)
    if (D == old.D + 1) {
      low <- low / mult + x[i]
      high <- high * mult - x[i] + x[i+D-1]/mult^(D-1) + x[i+D]/mult^D
      norm <- norm + 2 / mult^D
    } else if (D == old.D) {
      low <- low / mult - x[i-(D+1)]/mult^(D+1) + x[i]
      high <- high * mult - x[i] + x[i+D]/mult^D
    } else {
      low <- low / mult - x[i-(D+2)]/mult^(D+2) - x[i-(D+1)]/mult^(D+1) + x[i]
      high <- high * mult - x[i]
      norm <- norm - 2 / mult^(D+1)
    }

    # For numerical stability, recompute high every so often
    if (i %% 50 == 0) {
      rng <- (i+1):(i+D)
      expabs <- exp(-abs(i-rng)/delta)
      high <- sum(x[rng] * expabs)
    }

    ret[i] <- (low+high)/norm
    old.D <- D
  }
  return(ret)
}
```

R code like `josilber2` can often be sped up considerably using the `Rcpp` package:

```
library(Rcpp)
josilber3 <- cppFunction(
"
NumericVector josilber3(NumericVector x) {
  double delta = 10.0;
  NumericVector ret(x.size(), 0.0);
  ret[0] = x[0];
  double low = x[0];
  double high = 0.0;
  double norm = 1.0;
  int oldD = 0;
  double mult = exp(1/delta);
  for (int i=1; i < x.size(); ++i) {
    int D = i;
    if (x.size()-i-1 < D)  D = x.size()-i-1;
    if (30 < D)  D = 30;
    if (D == oldD + 1) {
      low = low / mult + x[i];
      high = high * mult - x[i] + x[i+D-1]/pow(mult, D-1) + x[i+D]/pow(mult, D);
      norm = norm + 2 / pow(mult, D);
    } else if (D == oldD) {
      low = low / mult - x[i-(D+1)]/pow(mult, D+1) + x[i];
      high = high * mult - x[i] + x[i+D]/pow(mult, D);
    } else {
      low = low / mult - x[i-(D+2)]/pow(mult, D+2) - x[i-(D+1)]/pow(mult, D+1) + x[i];
      high = high * mult - x[i];
      norm = norm - 2 / pow(mult, D+1);
    }

    if (i % 50 == 0) {
      high = 0.0;
      for (int j=i+1; j <= i+D; ++j) {
        high += x[j] * exp((i-j)/delta);
      }
    }

    ret[i] = (low+high)/norm;
    oldD = D;
  }
  return ret;
}")
```

We can now benchmark the improvements from these three new approaches:

```
all.equal(umair.fxn(uma), josilber1(uma))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(umair.fxn(uma), josilber2(uma))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(umair.fxn(uma), josilber3(uma$Vehicle.velocity))
# [1] TRUE
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(umair.fxn(uma), josilber1(uma), josilber2(uma), josilber3(uma$Vehicle.velocity))
# Unit: microseconds
#                             expr        min          lq         mean     median         uq        max neval
#                   umair.fxn(uma) 370006.728 382327.4115 398554.71080 393495.052 404186.153 572801.355   100
#                   josilber1(uma)  12879.268  13640.1310  15981.82099  14265.610  14805.419  28959.230   100
#                   josilber2(uma)   4324.724   4502.8125   5753.47088   4918.835   5244.309  17328.797   100
#  josilber3(uma$Vehicle.velocity)     41.582     54.5235     57.76919     57.435     60.099     90.998   100
```

We got a lot of improvement (25x) with the simpler `josilber1` and a 70x total speedup with `josilber2` (the advantage would be more with a larger delta value). With `josilber3` we achieve a 6800x speedup, getting the runtime all the way down to 54 microseconds to process a single vehicle!

Comment: Thanks for your answer +josilber. I really have to read it very carefully to get what's going on. I am also trying `dplyr`.

Comment: @umairdurrani I've updated to include an `Rcpp` solution, which is much faster than the other two.

Comment: Ahh! I don't know nothing about C++ and hence Rcpp. And when I run it, I get `NULL`. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @umairdurrani do you have Rcpp installed? The code I posted creates a function (`josilber3`) that takes a vector (you would pass `uma$Vehicle.velocity`) and runs the exponential smoothing on it.

Comment: @umairdurrani note that even using `josilber2`, which is implemented in pure R, should give you a runtime of 2 minutes instead of 3 hours for all your vehicles. Using `josilber3` should give you a total runtime of about 0.03 seconds.

Comment: I'll check if I run `library(Rcpp)` for josilber3 as soon as I get the chance today. For josilber2, I didn't understand the numerical stability part. I want to run the code once. If there are any chances of unstable data frame, I think that is risky for future analyses using it. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @umairdurrani the code gives identical results to your posted code or to `josilber1` (you can see this from the `all.equal` lines in the benchmarking). I just occasionally recompute `high` exactly instead of using the iterative approach. If you run the code any number of times it will give the same answer and they will all be identical to the results given by your code.

Comment: Thank you very much. josilber2 works great on the original data. Took only 30 seconds when I ran the function with dplyr.

Comment: I tried your function josilber2 for smoothing another variable 'Vehicle.acceleration2' by changing the delta to 40 and third argument in D as 120 (as required for acceleration smoothing). But the results were strange. I have gone through the code and it doesn't seem to have anything else specific to velocity smoothing. Do you think the function needs more adjustment, other than delta and 120 in D to smooth other variables?

Comment: @umairdurrani it should work fine -- you would have to post the data and describe what you mean by "the results were strange". For instance, did the result from `josilber2` differ from the result returned by your code?

Comment: It is perfect. I made a mistake while applying it. Thanks.